# How to run localhost in Microsoft edge when the Developer mode is disabled? Use case : Yeoman Generator

Tags: npm, permissions, containers, localhost, excel-addins

I am starting to code for an excel COM add-in via the Yeoman Generator.

The option "?Allow localhost loopback for Microsoft Edge Webview?" is not available for me.

In specific, the 'Developer mode' under edge://extension is disabled.

Wonder if there are any get around of this?

My thoughts:

1. Instead of using Edge, to use other browsers, such as the Chrome. However, mostly I don't have developer permission for them as well.
2. Any container techniques allow running localhost via a package rather than the system runtime?

I found many testing commands to test if the localhost is functional, such as:

CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -s

CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -a -n=Microsoft.win32webviewhost_cw5n1h2txyewy

However, lack of admin permission disallows many command runs.

The DEBUGGING GENERATORS option for Yeoman has no direct connection to my use case:
https://yeoman.io/authoring/debugging.html

Thank you!